# iOS : How to import a class to make it a parent class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

What's the difference between `#import <someclass.h>` **and** `#import "someclass.h" ?

And here's is what I think,

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
#import "classname.h" // This means importing a class within the same project

#import <classname.h> // This means importing a class from the local directory

@interface DerviedClass : ParentClass // This is inheritance
```

By using all these we can use another class's methods and properties.

My question is at what time these things should be used exactly and why?

Comment: It seems you have answered your questions.

Comment: Do you expect is to post a course about object-oriented programming?

Comment: `"classname.h"` is user header and `<classname.h>` is system header.

Answer (score 0):

`#import <>` imports a file from the system search path (starting with /usr/include usually)

`#include ""` imports a file from the user search path (starting with . usually)

Although both importation paths are very different in an Objective-C build environment, the basic distinction is still there and is reflected in setting such as "Always Search User Paths"

Generally speaking you should use `<>` for system and external includes and `""` for project includes.